# Can a polynomial have uncountably many indeterminates?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am writing up some stuff on polynomials with arbitrarily many variables over/with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$. While doing this, I vaguely remembered reading something about 'polynomials with uncountably many indeterminates,' or something along those lines, but can't find anything about it now that I look for it.

**My question:** is it sensible to say a polynomial may have 'uncountably many indeterminates'? What does this...mean? Are we not just handling some element of a polynomial ring $K[x_1,x_2\dots x_n]$, which obviously has countably many indeterminates?

Comment: a polynomial ring is just a free $k$-algebra over a set $X$ (the variables), if you now choose $X$ to be uncountable you get the ring of polynomials in uncountably many variables, but it is highly nonnoetherian, and hence quite ill behaved.

Comment: Yes, we have $K[x_i\mid i\in \Bbb R]$, why not?

Comment: @DietrichBurde you mean $i \in \mathbb{R}$, don't you? And sorry, meant "nonnoetherian"!

Comment: @Enkidu Ah, sorry, you are right. Uncountably many, not infinitely many.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to OP is No, a polynomial can't have infinitely many variables.
It is the polynomial ring that has infinitely many variables, not any polynomial.

By definition, a polynomial has only finitely many non-zero coefficients, hence only finitely many variables will appear.